# AngularJs How to pass the complex object in directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

iI have this directive :

```
amDirective.directive('directiveList', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           'event': '&onEvent'
        },
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: ''
    };
});
```

and in my page html

```
<div data-dy-directive-list data-elements="elements" on-event="listItemClicked(item)"></div>
```

and in my directive- template html

```
 <table class="table" data-ng-show="elements!=null && elements.length>0">

    <tr  data-ng-repeat="element in elements">                     
        <td><span  data-ng-click="event(element)">{{element.title}}</span></td>           
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>   
</table>
```

How can I pass in my directive the complex object "item"?

Answer (score 0):

From your directive (either controller or link function) you would call: `scope.event({item: item})`, passing a named map from argument names to values to provide to the callback.

Example:

```
amDirective.directive('directiveList', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           'event': '&onEvent'
        },
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: '',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind('click', function() {
            scope.event({ item:  { hello: 'world', x: 3 } });
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<a directive-list on-event="myHandler(item)">Click Me<a>
```

[Here's an example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/x8tfKEnfVmjk7mxVuP6E?p=preview).

See: [Can an angular directive pass arguments to functions in expressions specified in the directive's attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889615/can-an-angular-directive-pass-arguments-to-functions-in-expressions-specified-in)

Answer (score 0):

angular directives use '&' to bind to parent scope expressions.
It means that your directive would evaluate it when an event occurs inside the directive.

#### Example

```
app.directive('directiveList', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           'event': '&onEvent'
        },
        link: function(scope){
          var myItem = {}
          scope.event = function(item) {
          element.bind('click', function(){
            scope.event({item: myItem})
          })
        }
    };
});
```

If you want to raise an event from the parent scope and let your directive know you should use "="

#### Example

```
app.directive('directiveList', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           'event': '=onEvent'
        },
        link: function(scope){

          scope.event = function(item) {
             // manipulate item
             return "something";
          }

        }
    };
});
```