# AngularJS pass clicked item through custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am working on writing a custom directive.

```
<ng-selectbox select-function="selectitem(codes)" items="codes"></ng-selectbox> 

code.controller("codeCtrl", function($scope) {  
  $scope.selectitem = function(item){
    alert(item);
  };
});

code.directive("ngSelectbox", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      items: "=",
      selectFunction: "&"
    },
    template:
    "<div>" +
    "<ul ng-repeat='item in items'>" +
    "<li ng-click='selectFunction(item)'>{{item.TYPE}}</li>" +
    "</ul>" +
    "</div>"
  };
});
```

when the item in ng-repeat was clicked,
I would like to pass the clicked item through selectFunction,
but it didn't work. :(

I have no idea what parameter should I put in the html select-function.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change your template to

`"<li ng-click='selectFunction({item:item})'>{{item.TYPE}}</li>"`

and check whether it works.

Check my really old answer for more context [Can an angular directive pass arguments to functions in expressions specified in the directive's attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889615/can-an-angular-directive-pass-arguments-to-functions-in-expressions-specified-in/19890548#19890548)