# loop function through nested directive - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to loop a function through a nested directive. From the `console.info` in `myCtrl` I would expect the string `"this should be logged"`.

```
angular.module('myApp')
      .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.aFunction = function(input) {
          console.info(input.message);
        }
      })
      .directive('levelOneDirective', function () {
        return {
          templateUrl: '<level-two-directive aFunction="aFunction(object)"></level-two-directive>',
          restrict: 'EA',
          scope: {
            aFunction:"&"
          },
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          }
        };
      })
      .directive('levelTwoDirective', function () {
        return {
          templateUrl: '<div ng-click="aFunction({message: 'this should be logged'})"></div>',
          restrict: 'EA',
          scope: {
            aFunction:"&"
          },
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          }
        };
      });
```

And in my `index.html` I have something like:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <level-one-directive aFunction="aFunction(object)"></level-one-directive>
</div>
```

But the console says `undefined`.

How to connect a function through nested directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your code but I assume it's because you try to adjust it to the question (such as `aFunction` as attribute instead of `a-function` and `templateUrl` instead of `template`).

You can have a 2-way binding (`=`) in your directives (both of them):

```
scope: {
     aFunction:"="
},
```

And pass the function reference without the object:

```
<level-one-directive a-function="aFunction"></level-one-directive>
```

In the second directive HTML have:

```
<div ng-click="invokeFunction()"></div>
```

And then in the link function of your 2nd directive you can do:

```
scope.invokeFunction = function () {
    scope.aFunction({message: 'this should be logged'});
}
```

The above works and I find it more convenient than `&` binding, which as you can see, is not quite easy to work with, and frankly I haven't messed around enough with it to figure out how (and if possible) to pass arguments through it.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889615/can-an-angular-directive-pass-arguments-to-functions-in-expressions-specified-in), but it's binding straight on the link function, and you want it with an `ng-click` so it might not work for you. But perhaps you'll find your solution there.

Comment: I had this idea from here: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding
Great, thanks. Its working. Sorry, for the mistakes.